# How to order result by highest in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this search method in laravel where it takes complete sentence and break them into single words and compare them in the data base using the LIKE word

```
        $trim = new SearchTrim();
    $words = $trim->ProcessNeedle($query);

    $results = DB::table('projects')->where(function ($query) use ($words) {
        foreach($words as $item) {
            $query->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', "%$item%")
            ->orWhere('category', 'LIKE', "%$item%");
        }
    })->paginate(15);
```

Its working.. But the challenge is that I want to order the results the row that have the highest outputs from the queries. Any help please

Comment: You can't do this with mysql query. You have to use elasticsearch ot other full text search engine to get highest score by overlapping words

Comment: Oh, goodness.. Please do you have link to live examples?

Comment: Or at least a demonstration of what elasticsearch is sir

Comment: There is no quick solution. integration of elasticsearch takes lots of time and knowledge

Comment: Search in youtube fo "elasticsearch tutorial for beginner"